# Convert position and rotation from Blender to Unreal engine

Tags: python, blender, unreal-engine5, fbx, unreal

I am exporting keyframe coordinates and rotations from Blender(latest) as CSV via python, and using them to animate an object through code, in Unreal Engine 5.0.4. The positions are matching, but not the rotations. What I have tried:

- converted eulers from right hand z-up to left-hand z-up
- rotation quaternions
- world matrix transformation

I have strictly followed these:

- Imported the same model into both,  rotated the model in blender, towards the same "forward"
- Applied all transformations from object>>apply>>apply all transformations.
- Added basic rotations at different keyframe.
- Exported keyframe rotations as Euler, or Quaternions or world matrix.
- The Unreal script loads the angles as it is, without change.